# drupal reading array type fields

Tags: php, drupal

I have a multi value cck field.

I can read any single `id` with `node->field_multip[0][id]`.

How do I read all `ids`? I tried a for loop with `field_multip.length` but the page never finishes loading. What's the right way of doing this?

```
field_multip
   [0] 
      [id]
      [sec]
   [1]
      [id]
      [sec]
   [2]
      [id]
      [sec]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($node->field_multip as $key => $value) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: This did the job, but looks like I still need a way to get the length of the multi-value field for other reasons. I've started another question here if anyone can help with that specific question: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390947/finding-length-of-multi-value-field` Looks like drupal may be different.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$array = ...
foreach($array as $obj) {
   //do something with $obj->id...
}
```