# finding length of multi-value field

Tags: php, drupal

I have a multi-value cck field in a drupal node. The field is called `field_multip`. I need to know the number of items in this field, for example 3 in the case below

I would have thought that `length` would do the trick, but neither `$node->field_multip.length` nor `$node->field_multip.length()` worked for me.

```
field_multip
   [0] 
      [id]
      [sec]
   [1]
      [id]
      [sec]
   [2]
      [id]
      [sec]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use [count()](http://www.php.net/count)

```
$itemcount = count($node->field_multip);
```

Should do it.